# VS 2019 Community version 16.4.0 gives error for Test Explorer

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2019, xunit

VS19 community version is giving error.Checking Test Output Pane gives this error:

```
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestWindow.Controller.OperationBroker.<>c__DisplayClass17_0.<<OnSolutionOpened>b__0>d.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestWindow.Extensibility.ILoggerExtensions.<CallWithCatchAsync>d__9.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Telemetry.WindowsErrorReporting.WatsonReport.GetClrWatsonExceptionInfo(Exception exceptionObject)
```